# Postfixadmin Invalid Query

Tags: mysql, postfix

This is my first time running a postfixadmin, so in my setup.php, I'm getting this error

```
DEBUG INFORMATION:
Invalid query: Unknown column 'create_date' in 'mailbox'
```

I'm running it with MySQL.

So if i'm right, my guess is that i need to create a column? under mailbox table on the postfix database? but how or whats the right syntax into creating a timedate column? My knowledge with mysql and postfix are very minimal btw. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Paste the following into a file named `postfixadmin.sql`:

```
USE postfix;
CREATE TABLE mailbox (
  username varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  password varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  name varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  maildir varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  domain varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  create_date datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  change_date datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  active tinyint(4) NOT NULL default '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (username)
) TYPE=MyISAM COMMENT='Virtual Mailboxes';
```

then import the table structure by running:

```
$ mysql -u root -p < postfixadmin.sql
```